# Generalised derivative and derivative of functions of bounded variation

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a function Lebesgue-integrable on any finite interval and let $K$ be the space of infinitely differentiable equal to 0 outside a given finite interval. Be the *generalised derivative* of $f$ defined as the distribution $T':K\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by $$T'(\varphi)=-\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\varphi'(x)d\mu$$where the integral is Lebesgue's.
I read in Kolmogorov-Fomin's *Элементы теории функций и функционального анализа* that if $f$ is a function of bounded variation and its derivative as a function corresponds to its generalised derivative as a distribution, i.e. if $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f'(x)\varphi(x)d\mu=-\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\varphi'(x)d\mu$ for any $\varphi\in K$, then $f$ is absolutely continuous.

I think I have been able to prove, by using the decomposition $f=H+\psi+\chi$ where $H$ is a step function, $\psi$ is absolutely continuous and $\chi$ is singular (i.e. with $\chi'(x)=0$ for almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}$), that, if the derivative of $f$ as a function corresponds to its generalised derivative as a distribution, then $f$ is identical to an absolutely continuous function *almost everywhere*, but I am not sure it holds *everywhere* and, if it did, I am not able to prove it. Does anybody know more about this fact? $\infty$ thanks!

I apologise in advance if I had used some scarcely formal and rigourous language, but the book I am following is quite informal and I fear I am assimilating not-so-good customs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this problem doesn't depend on knowing much about $f$. If $f$, $g$ are locally integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, and if
$$
        \int f\varphi'\,dx = -\int g\varphi\,dx,\;\;\; \varphi\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})
$$
then $f$ is equal a.e. to a continuous function $\tilde{f}$, and $\tilde{f}$ is absolutely continuous with $\tilde{f}'=g$ a.e..

To see this, choose $\varphi'$ to converge to $\frac{1}{\epsilon}\chi_{[a-\epsilon,a]}-\frac{1}{\delta}\chi_{[b,b+\delta]}$ for $0 < \epsilon,\delta$ and $a \le b$, and $\varphi$ to converge to the integral of this function (which has $0$ total integral.) Then you get
$$
          \frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a}f\,dx-\frac{1}{\delta}\int_{b}^{b+\delta}f\,dx =-\int_{a-\epsilon}^{b+\delta}g\left[\int_{a-\epsilon}^{x}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\chi_{[a-\epsilon,a]}+\frac{1}{\delta}\chi_{[b,b+\delta]}\,dt\right]dx.
$$
The inner integral on the right converges to $\chi_{[a,b]}$ as $\epsilon\downarrow$ and $\delta\downarrow 0$, and it remains uniformly bounded by $1$ in the process. So the limit of the expression on the right exists as $\epsilon \downarrow 0$, $\delta\downarrow 0$, whether one at a time, or together. That means that the limits on the left also exist at every $a$, $b$. We know that the limits on the left are left- and right-hand derivatives of $\int_{0}^{x}f\,dt$, and by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, those limits are equal a.e. to $f$. So, we have the a.e. equality
$$
                 f(a)-f(b) = -\int_{a}^{b}g\,dx.
$$
The function on the right is continuous in $a$, $b$, which means that $f$ is equal a.e. to a continuous function $\tilde{f}$, and $\tilde{f}$ is absolutely continuous with $\tilde{f}'=g$ a.e..

**Mollifier:** You are concerned that the weak relation
$$
    \int_{\mathbb{R}}f'\varphi d\mu = -\int_{\mathbb{R}}f\varphi' d\mu,\;\; \varphi\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R})
$$
cannot necessarily be strengthened to allow $\varphi$ to be a compactly supported absolutely continuous function instead. You can prove that such a thing can be done by finding $\eta \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R})$ which is

- non-negative, non-vanishing and constant in a neighborhood of $x=0$,
- symmetric about $x=0$,
- supported in $[-1,1]$,
- bounded between $0$ and $\eta(0)$, and
- normalized so that $\int \eta d\mu =1$.

Then one defines
$$
                    \eta_{n}(x) = n\eta(nx)
$$
so that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\eta_{n}\,d\mu =1$ for all $n$. For any compactly supported absolutely continuous function $\varphi$, define
$$
           \varphi_{n} = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\eta_{n}(x-y)\varphi(y)\,d\mu(y).
$$
The function $\varphi_{n}$ is in $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R})$. Because $\eta_{n}$ is supported in $[-1/n,1/n]$, and $\varphi$ is continuous, then $\varphi_{n}$ converges uniformly to $\varphi$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. And, because $\varphi$ is absolutely continuous, then
$$
     \varphi_{n}' = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\eta_{n}'(x-y)\varphi(y)\,d\mu(y)=
             -\int_{\mathbb{R}}\eta_{n}(x-y)\varphi'(y)\,d\mu(y).           
$$
For my case $\varphi'$ is piecewise continuous, and the right side then converges pointwise everywhere to mean of the left- and right-hand limits of $\varphi'$, and it remains uniformly bounded by any bound for $\varphi'$. Thus, your weak equation
$$
              \int f'\varphi_{n}d\mu = -\int f\varphi_{n}'d\mu
$$
becomes the following in the limit
$$
               \int f'\varphi d\mu = -\int f \varphi' d\mu.
$$
For a general absolutely continuous $\varphi$, you can show that $\varphi_{n}$ converges uniformly to $\varphi$ and $\varphi_{n}'$ converges in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ to $\varphi'$.

Mollifiers are very useful for extending integral equations for $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{0}$ functions to more general functions. If $\varphi$ has $k$ continuous derivatives that are compactly supported, then $\varphi_{n}$ and all $k$ derivatives converge uniformly to the corresponding derivatives of $\varphi$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you be so kind to tell me why the inner integral on the right converges (I think you use Levi's monotone convergence theorem) to $\chi_{[a,b]}$: I'd calculate it if $x\in[a,b]$ as 1, if $x\in[b,b+\delta]$ as $1+(x-b/\delta)$, if $x\geq b+\delta$ as 2. I'm obviously deliring. As to how to be sure that one can find such $\varphi'$ and $\varphi$, I'm not sure whether I've got the tools to understand it, but what's the reason why we know that it's possible? Thank you so much again!!!

Comment: @DavideZena : The inner integral on the right is the piecewise linear function that is $0$ for $x \le a-\epsilon$, ramps linearly to $1$ at $x=a$, stays $1$ to $x=b$, and then ramps linearly back to $0$ at $x=b+\delta$, after which is stays $0$. Visualize what happens as either $\epsilon$ or $\delta$ tend down to $0$. You have bounded convergence.

Comment: Excuse me: you're describing $\int_{a-\epsilon}^x\frac{1}{\epsilon}\chi_{[a-\epsilon,a]}-\frac{1}{\delta}\chi_{[b,b+\delta]}dt$, have I understood? As to the properties of bounded convergence, I fear I have not found such a concept in my calculus studies: has the fact you're using the name of a major theorem that I could find on line or in written reference? Thank you so much again!!!

Comment: @DavideZena : The Bounded Convergence Theorem is a corollary of the Dominated Convergence Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Bounded_convergence_theorem . As the inner integral converges, it does so in a way that it remains uniformly bounded. But you can also argue directly without much trouble.

Comment: Interesting corollary of Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem. Thank you so much again!!!

Comment: I hoped I could find some hint in the following part of Kolmogorov-Fomin's about how to see that a $\varphi'$ (uniformly, I think) converging to $\frac{1}{\epsilon}\chi_{[a-\epsilon,a]}+\frac{1}{\delta}\chi_{[b,b+\delta]}$ exists, but I could find no idea there. How can it be proved? I could post a specifical question if you considered it better. Thank you very much and have a happy new year!

Comment: @DavideZena : That's not what exists. It's the integral of that function $h_{a,b,\epsilon,\delta}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\left[\frac{1}{\epsilon}\chi_{[a-\epsilon ,a]}(t)+\frac{1}{\delta}\chi_{[b,b+\delta]}(t)\right]\,dt$ that has a limit as either or both $\delta$, $\epsilon$ tend to $0$. Therefore, $\int_{\mathcal{R}}g(x)h_{a,b,\epsilon,\delta}(x)dx$ has a limit as either or both of $\epsilon,\delta$ tend to $0$. Hence, the left side of the equation must have limits, which means that $\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a}fdx$ has a limit as $\epsilon\downarrow 0$, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the comment!! Forgive me, I'm not understanding: what does the $\varphi'$ in "To see this, choose $\varphi'$..." (4$^\text{th}$ line) converge to and in what sense does it converge?

Comment: @DavideZena : it doesn't, but the integral with respect to it must converge, because the other side of the integral weak equation converges, which is how you conclude that $\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a}f\,dx$ converges as $\epsilon\downarrow 0$. I've done nothing illegal in arriving at the equation; then I take limits of that legal equation, knowing that the right side converges, which forces the left side to converge. :)

Comment: Forgive me: I think I'm understanding nothing: how do you derive $\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a}f\,dx-\frac{1}{\delta}\int_{b}^{b+\delta}f\,dx =-\int_{a-\epsilon}^{b+\delta}g\left[\int_{a-\epsilon}^{x}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\chi_{[a-\epsilon,a]}+\frac{1}{\delta}\chi_{[b,b+\delta]}\,dt\right]dx$ from $ \int f\varphi'\,dx = -\int g\varphi\,dx$? Haven't you chosen "$\varphi'$ to converge to $\frac{1}{\epsilon}\chi_{[a-\epsilon,a]}-\frac{1}{\delta}\chi_{[b,b+\delta]}$ for $0 < \epsilon,\delta$ and $a \le b$, and $\varphi$ to converge to the integral of this function"?

Comment: @DavideZena : Identify $\varphi$ and identify its derivative $\varphi'$. $\varphi$ is a piecewise linear function.

Comment: Mmh... Is the key that $\int_{a-\epsilon}^{x}\frac{1}{\epsilon} \chi_{[a-\epsilon,a]}+\frac{1}{\delta} \chi_{[b,b+\delta]}\,dt$ (or $\int_{a-\epsilon}^{x}\frac{1}{\epsilon} \chi_{[a-\epsilon,a]}-\frac{1}{\delta} \chi_{[b,b+\delta]}\,dt$?) belongs to $K=C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, without requiring that $\varphi'$ converges to $\frac{1}{\epsilon}\chi_{[a-\epsilon,a]}-\frac{1}{\delta}\chi_{[b,b+\delta]}$?

Comment: @DavideZena : As I've mentioned before, a mollification argument will allow you to use absolutely continuous functions $\varphi$ instead of $C^{\infty}_{0}$ functions for test functions. You get the same weak derivatives.

Comment: Forgive me once more: could you explicitly word the mollification argument so that, when I study mollification, I'll be able to understand your answer (where you've recently said that $\varphi'$ does NOT converge to $\frac{1}{\epsilon}\chi_{[a-\epsilon,a]}-\frac{1}{\delta}\chi_{[b,b+\delta]}$: have I undesrtood?)? I $\aleph_1$-ly thank you and wish you a happy 2015!

Comment: @DavideZena : I've added material about mollifiers to get you started. Based on your interests, I'm guessing this is something you'll want to know about at some point. This basic intro will help you get up to a working level with such things. The Poisson kernel, the Fej\'er kernel, and other kernels from PDES are mollifiers, but they're not compactly supported. And that's the genesis of the ideas behind mollifiers: positive convolution kernels that smooth data.

Comment: @DavideZena : Using the mollification argument, you can directly use the piecewise linear continuous function $\varphi_{a,b,\epsilon,\delta}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}\left[\frac{1}{\epsilon}\chi_{[a- \epsilon,a]}(t)-\frac{1}{\delta}\chi_{[b,b+\delta]}(t)\right]dt$ in the weak equation that you have. At least that's the end effect. Note: this $\varphi$ is compactly supported.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tremendously interesting facts you tell me! I've posted a specifical question on the facts you've added: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087837/approximating-a-piecewise-continuous-function-with-a-function-in-mathcalc